# View documentation of packages installed into a cabal sandbox

Tags: haskell, sandbox, cabal

Is there a way to view the documentation of any package I installed in a cabal sandbox? Currently I have a script that places the documentation in a common path so I can view it with a simple server script, but I imagine there's a better or more accepted way of doing this.

To be clear, I do not mean cabal-dev, but the sandboxing tools in the latest cabal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you install packages into sandbox with documentation enabled (`cabal install --enable-documentation` or `documentation: True` in `./cabal.config`), the generated documentation will be put under `./.cabal-sandbox/share/doc/$arch-$os-$compiler/$pkigid`. In other words, this works in the same way as with the user package DB (one exception is that a local documentation index is not created in the sandbox case - this is a [known issue](https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/1337)).

Comment: I was able to find the documentation, but to make it easy to read in a browser I had to make a script. Is there no appropriate way to access it, that makes it possible to view all the installed libraries in a browser?

Comment: It appears I misread your answer. Indeed if there was a sandbox local index of the packages, that would solve my problem. It appears I'm stuck with my script for the time being.